Can't modify react-apex-chart radial bar thickness
I'm trying to reduce the thickness of my radial bar chart but I can't find any way to do this
enter image description here
and here is my chart options :
const chartOptions = {
        series: [40],
        options: {
            chart: {
                height: 350,
                type: 'radialBar',
                toolbar: {
                    show: true
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                radialBar: {
                    hollow: {
                        margin: 0,
                        size: "20%",
                        background: "#293450"
                    },
                    track: {
                        dropShadow: {
                            enabled: true,
                            top: 2,
                            left: 0,
                            blur: 4,
                            opacity: 0.15,
                        },
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        showOn: "always",
                        name: {
                            offsetY: -10,
                            color: "#fff",
                            fontSize: "13px"
                        },
                        value: {
                            color: "#fff",
                            fontSize: "30px",
                            show: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        fill: {
            type: "gradient",
            gradient: {
                shade: "dark",
                type: "vertical",
                gradientToColors: ["#05E996"],
                stops: [0, 100]
            }
        },
        stroke: {
            lineCap: 'round',
        },
        labels: ['APs count'],
    };

Am i missing something ?
Thanks in advance !
Updating chart options to get thinner bar width

You can simply do it by increasing the percentage of hollow:{ size: "60%(upto your requirement)"}.
Code:


   plotOptions: {
            radialBar: {
                    hollow: {
                        margin: 0,
                        size: "60%",
                        background: "#293450"
                            },
                        }
                 }



